# How do I reset a dispatcherTimer?

Tags: c#

How do I reset a dispatcherTimer?

in my app I start a timer and later on I use the dispatcherTimer.Stop method to stop and the timer stops. I close the application and run it again and the timer doesn't start at zero. How do I set the timer to reset and start at zero?

Comment: To anybody that might want to tackle this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328880/how-to-use-dispatchertimer-stop-in-a-different-function

Comment: Since there is no DispatcherTimer tick count. What do you mean by the timer does not start at zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you are calling 'timer count' is:

```
string etime = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
```

Since DateTime.Now is based on the computers realtime clock, you are going to get a different value for seconds based on when you start the program.

You want:

```
starttime = DateTime.Now;
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

and:

```
string etime = (DateTime.Now - startTime).Seconds.ToString();
```

Comment: What I mean is, or maybe I'm just getting this dispatchertimer concept wrong, is that I initiate a timer (does that timer start at zero?) and then when I stop it I want to reset that timer for future use.

Answer (score 3):

this will reset a dispatchertimer.

```
timer.Stop();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);  // 1sec
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Timers count down. This is true for all software timers I know of. You give it a specified time, and it counts down, triggering an event when it reaches zero.

If you want to *measure* elapsed time, then you can use something like a `StopWatch`, which does count up.